# Category description special character issue - M2

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

Using this I can update the category description but special characters are removed.

```
$category_Id = 6;
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->setStoreId(0)->load($category_Id);
$category->setDescription("Test1/4"" Test° ");
$category->save();
```

How can I keep a special character with description text?

any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with - html_entity_decode(htmlentities(utf8_decode(strip_tags($description))));  ?

Comment: It's not working 1/4 removed

Comment: used only html_entity_decode()

Answer (score 0):

$category_Id = 6;

$description="Test1/4"" Test";

$description=html_entity_decode($description)

$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->setStoreId(0)->load($category_Id);

$category->setDescription($description);

$category->save();